# Vimeo API returns wrong counts

Tags: api, comments, vimeo, vimeo-api

Looking at a Vimeo video, I see the comment count including replies. However, counting the comments on the page or the comments from the comment API I get a different count.

For example, for this video https://vimeo.com/68444037 the comment count on the page is saying 41 comments, but there are actually 38 comments plus one reply. I called the latest Vimeo API https://api.vimeo.com/videos/68444037/comments and got the same, 38 comments, and one reply.

Is the count here wrong? or there are comments somewhere else, like in a channel or a category?

Answer (score 0):

The total comment count returned in the `/videos/68444037` response is likely including deleted comments or comments marked as spam. The total comment count returned in `/videos/68444037/comments` is the more accurate count, as it excludes spam or deleted comments. It should also be inclusive of threaded reply comments.

Comment: Thank you! That helped. 
Maybe my API call results wasn't clear: even with the API call https://api.vimeo.com/videos/68444037/comments, I get "total":41 but if I count messages and count of replies on them I still get 38+1.